# Covariance estimation: Shrinkage estimation

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, estimation, covariance, covariance-matrix

I am trying to understand why the covariance estimation shrinkage works. Is there any theory behind any of these approach?

For instance, I was reading this paper: http://www.ledoit.net/honey.pdf

However, not much discussion why it works, from a theoretical perspective. I am not a heavy theoretician, please don't throw me tons of math. I only know the basic stats and basic probability.

Comment: Please provide more details (instead of a link) on what you mean by "covariance estimation shrinkage works".